# JSF persistance file issue

Tags: java, jpa, jsf-2, jboss7.x

Let me start by saying I am a total noob in Java.

I am building a Jboss JSF app. I have a file called `DefaultDS-ds.xml` with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema">
 <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/DefaultDS" enabled="true" 
     use-java-context="true" pool-name="DefaultDS">
  <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/CinemaDb</connection-url>
  <driver>mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar</driver>
  <pool></pool>
  <security>
   <user-name>root</user-name>
   <password>test123</password>
  </security>
 </datasource>
</datasources>
```

and a `persistence.xml` with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="user-unit">
        <class>model.User</class>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/DefaultDS</jta-data-source>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

however, when deploying my app I get:

```
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.DefaultDS (missing) dependents: [service jboss.persistenceunit."dynamic-web.war#user-unit"]
```

I cannot seem to find the answer to this problem myself (if it is something simple - please accept my appologies), so can anyone help me?

**EDIT**: after fidling around with the folder structure, here is the new structure

```
dynamic-web
+---WEB-INF
¦   faces-config.xml
¦   web.xml
¦   DefaultDS-ds.xml
¦
+---classes
¦   ¦
¦   +---META-INF
¦           MANIFEST.MF
¦           persistence.xml
¦
+---lib
        mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar
```

and the new error:

```
16:40:00,475 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015871: Deploy of deployment "mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar" was rolled back with no failure message
16:40:00,479 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "dynamic-web.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.data-source.jboss/datasources/DefaultDSjboss.jdbc-driver.mysql-connector-java-5_0_8-bin_jarMissing[jboss.data-source.jboss/datasources/DefaultDSjboss.jdbc-driver.mysql-connector-java-5_0_8-bin_jar]"]}
16:40:00,483 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-11) JBAS010409: Unbound data source [jboss/datasources/DefaultDS]
16:40:00,487 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-14) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment dynamic-web.war in 11ms
16:40:00,487 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-9) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar in 11ms
16:40:00,488 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql-connector-java-5_0_8-bin_jar (missing) dependents: [service jboss.data-source.jboss/datasources/DefaultDS]
```

Comment: Can you verify whether data source is created properly in JBoss, JNDI mapping etc. in admin console.

Comment: `13:51:32,752 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-10) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]`  well this is strange....

Comment: @NayanWadekar, can you point me how to access that console? I cannot seem to acces it at `http://localhost:8080/admin-console` (as guides say)

Comment: No, it isn't strange. ExampleDS is provided by default, can refer documentation to setup new datasource properly, might help - https://community.jboss.org/wiki/DataSourceConfigurationInAS7

Comment: @NayanWadekar Well DefaultDS does not get created. The site you gave me is confusing. Do I have to install the datasource on the server itself, or do I have to make changes to my project. Also, some links in that article don't work

Answer (score 1):

after switching out the jar file with a new one ([this one](http://code.google.com/p/find-ur-pal/downloads/detail?name=mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar&)) the deploy suceeded